# Populating the list in g.select

Tags: select, grails

I need to programmatically load a list. 
Instead of:

```
<g:select 
       name="cars" 
       from="${Car.list()}" 
       value="${person?.cars*.id}" 
       optionKey="id"
       multiple="true" />
```

I would like to do it this because, the list is not always coming from the same source

```
g.select(name : searchfield.fieldName,                          
         class : "fillWidth searchfield",
         multiple : "true",
         from : ${ searchfield.fieldFrom },
         optionKey : searchfield.fieldKey,
         optionValue : searchfield.fieldValue)
```

The from does not load. with the list, I get an error message:

No signature of method: sample.SearchTagLib.$() is applicable for argument types: (sample.SearchTagLib$_getSelectField_closure5) values: [sample.SearchTagLib$_getSelectField_closure5@1187b50] Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), grep()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `${}` in the `from` option

```
g.select(name : searchfield.fieldName,                          
         class : "fillWidth searchfield",
         multiple : "true",
         from : searchfield.fieldFrom,
         optionKey : searchfield.fieldKey,
         optionValue : searchfield.fieldValue)
```

In Groovy code `${}` is a way to put Groovy expressions inside double quoted GStrings, if you're not in a GString you can just use the expression directly without wrapping it in `${}`.

---

**Edit** from your comment

> The fieldFrom at this point is a string which would get its value from a database. So the value in the DB is "Car.list()" which in the prototype I need to convert to a bound able or execute-able line of code.

It's not generally recommended to allow your app to execute arbitrary snippets of Groovy code provided by users (for obvious security reasons).  As long as the code snippets come from a secure source such as a trusted admin user then fair enough, it is possible using `GroovyShell`

```
def from = new GroovyShell().evaluate(searchfield.fieldFrom)
```

but this is likely to be rather inefficient, creating a new classloader and parsing and compiling a whole Groovy script class every time.  If the `fieldFrom` values are intended to always be pulling something from the database (i.e. they'll always be something like `Car.list()` or `Vehicle.findAllByNumberOfWheelsGreaterThan(2)`, rather than arbitrary Groovy like `[1,2,3]`) then it might be better to store HQL expressions in `fieldFrom` and run them using `executeQuery`

```
def from = AnyDomainClass.executeQuery(searchfield.fieldFrom)
```

(`executeQuery` is a static GORM method, you need to call it on a specific domain class but it can return results of any type).  The HQL equivalent of `Car.list()` would be "`from Car`", the equivalent of `Vehicle.findAllByNumberOfWheelsGreaterThan(2)` would be "`from Vehicle where numberOfWheels > 2`", etc.

Comment: doing does not produce an error, it parses the value like a string, but if searchfield.fieldFrom = Car.list() I would like it to get the list of available cars.  This will be table driven to the user

Comment: @user2498465 that's exactly what it _should_ do. What exactly is `searchField` and how do you set it up?

Comment: The fieldFrom at this point is a string which would get its value from  a database.  So the value in the DB is "Car.list()" which in the prototype I need to convert to a bound able  or execute-able line of code.

Comment: @user2498465 I see, I've added a few possible suggestions.

Comment: Thanks the GroovyShell worked, and the list is from a safe source. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use strings as the attribute name:

```
g.select('name' : searchfield.fieldName,                          
         'class' : "fillWidth searchfield",
         'multiple' : "true",
         'from' : ${ searchfield.fieldFrom },
         'optionKey' : searchfield.fieldKey,
         'optionValue' : searchfield.fieldValue)
```